Can CSS have an arbitrary number of elements inside a pseudo-selector?
DOM snippet
ul.this>li>ul                                  ->match
ul.this>li>div>ul                              ->match
ul.this>li>div>div>ul                          ->match
ul.this>li>div>menu>div>nav>div>div>div>div>ul ->match
ul.this>li>ul>li>div>ul                        ->dont match
ul.this>li>div>ul>li>div>ul                    ->dont match

Is there a better way in CSS than stating:
ul.this>li>ul, ul.this>li>:not(ul)>ul, ul.this>li>:not(ul)>:not(ul)>ul,
ul.this>li>:not(ul)>:not(ul)>:not(ul)>ul,
ul.this>li>:not(ul)>:not(ul)>:not(ul)>:not(ul)>ul,
ul.this>li>:not(ul)>:not(ul)>:not(ul)>:not(ul)>:not(ul)>ul

…as that will still fail the n+1 case, but you have to end somewhere. Something like /(ul)+/ in regex?
Read:
Any ul inside and descending ul.this that has in its path from ul.this to the resulting ul no other ul in between.

What use-case are you trying to solve by asking the question? There's probably a way to do what you want, but without seeing an example of what you're trying to do it's hard (for me at least) to offer an answer. Can you post a snippet of your "[mcve]" HTML and explain what should and shouldn't be selected?

@DavidThomas What for? This is a purposefully generic question. I'm not interested in a workaround/hack for a specific problem (in a specific problem I'd know the number of descendats) but for a generic problem.

You just want li ul…? If not, what exactly are you trying to match or not match?

@deceze
Any ul inside and descending this li that has in its path from li to the resulting ul no other ul in between.

li :not(ul) ul?

@deceze Think like this: nav>$>ul>li>$>ul>li>$>ul $ = 'anything that is not ul in any number including nothing at all'

Trying to get my brain round this: you want the first ul descendant of a given li? Is that correct?

"anything that is not ul in any number including nothing at all" — li > ul, li :not(ul) ul…?

"Any ul inside and descending this li that has in its path from li to the resulting ul no other ul in between.". What do you mean by "this li"?  Your example li>ul,li>:not(ul.... matches ul descendants of any li. That matters because in valid HTML, all children of ul elements that can themselves contain a ul element must be an li element. So a ul element that's a descendant of a ul element that's a descendant of a given li - something that you don't want to match - will, by necessity be the descendant of a different li that doesn't have an intervening ul element.

On the other hand, if you mean a specific li, say one with an id of "myli", then your requirement is met simply by #myli ul:not(#myli ul ul)

@AHaworth Yes. li>ul should match. li>:not(ul)>ul should match. Also li>[:not(ul) times n]>ul should match.

@deceze li > ul, li :not(ul) ul would match li>ul>li>div>ul, because it would take the first li, take the second li (it not a ul) and then match the final ul. It should not, there is an ul in between. But is should match li>div>div>menu>div>div>ul, as there is no ul in between.

It would help a lot if you presented some HTML/structure and told us what you wish and don’t wish to match within it.

@deceze I still think my inital question is as exact as it can be. But i added a DOM snippet. Working this out in HTML would be a hilariously lot of useless code.

You added some CSS selectors - please add some examples of the related HTML. And in particular indicate how the relevant li is chosen - does it have a specific class for example?

@AHaworth OP added an example of the structure, just not in HTML notation…

Your question may have been exact, but to make it clearly comprehensible for any reader, a more verbose explanation is always helpful. It's the difference between a terse one liner and an unrolled loop.

ul.this ul:not(ul.this ul ul) {/*...*/}
